# How to exclude documentation files from Fody/Costura?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fody-costura

When using Fody/Costura in my solution, the resulting executable is much larger than the combined size of the assemblies that have `Copy Local` option set to `True`.

When I inspect the `debug` and `release` directories I see a bunch of XML files files that correspond to those assemblies that have their 'Generate XML documentation' option in the Build property set to `true`. Some of those are pretty big. So my guess is that Fody/Costura somehow extracts and packages those as well, resulting in the larger file size. Is that assessment correct?

If so, is there a safe way to exclude those?

Comment: I  figured out a way to decrease the file size. In my project, I referenced a dll by pointing to it in the project's Release folder. It contains a whole bunch of other dll's all with xml documentation. Those XML files got pulled in to my current project. Since I only needed the single dll, I copied it to a folder local to my current project and referenced that. That decreased the assembly size by 50%.